# Toggle Mute sound in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have several tracks of audio that are in sinc. I would like to have one "TitleMusic" ON from the start,  And allow the user to toggle ON and off the other tracks. My code As it stands has the "TitleMusic" playing from the start with all the other tracks playing too. I need to switch "track8" and all the other tracks (not showing) around so they are off at the start.This took me a long time to get to this point, I just need some help turning it around. Thanks

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var soundOn:Boolean = true;//This music is ON when we start
var myMusic:TitleMusic = new TitleMusic();
var myChannel1:SoundChannel = myMusic.play(0,1000);//endless loop, in effect

var soundOn3:Boolean = true; //music is ON when we start
var myMusic3:track8 = new track8();
var myChannel3:SoundChannel = myMusic3.play(0,1000); // endless loop, in effect
var myTransform3:SoundTransform;

mySoundButton3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,toggleSound3);
mySoundButton3.buttonMode = true;
mySoundButton3.mouseChildren = false;

function toggleSound3(e:MouseEvent)
{
if(soundOn3)
{
// turn sound off

myTransform3 = new SoundTransform();
myTransform3.volume = 0; // silent
myChannel3.soundTransform = myTransform3;
soundOn3 = false;
mySoundButton3.myButtonText.text = "click to turn sound ON";
}
else // sound is off
{
// turn sound on

myTransform3 = new SoundTransform();
myTransform3.volume = 1; // full volume
myChannel3.soundTransform = myTransform3;
soundOn3 = true;
mySoundButton3.myButtonText.text = "click to turn sound OFF";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just put this line right after `mySoundButton3.mouseChildren = false;`:

```
toggleSound3(null);
```

---

Or, to be more efficient with memory, you could do this:

Take this line:

```
var myChannel3:SoundChannel = myMusic3.play(0,1000);
```

and change it to:

```
var myChannel3:SoundChannel;
```

This makes it so you're not actually starting the sound right away, but just creating the pointer for it (var)

Then, in your turn on block right after `// turn sound on`:

```
if(!myChannel13){
    myChannel3 = myMusic3.play(0,1000); 
}
```

This checks to see if you've started the sound yet, if not, it creates/starts the sound

You'll also want to change this line in your sound off block:

```
myChannel3.soundTransform = myTransform3;
```

to this

```
if(myChannel13){
    myChannel3.soundTransform = myTransform3;
}
```

That way, if the off button is clicked before the on button, it won't throw an error.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to get my head around it.  But wouldn't dropping ".play(0,1000)"from  var myChannel3:SoundChannel; turn that track off and therefore put it out of sinc with "TitleMusic" track?

Comment: Yes it would,  I missed the part about needing to be in sync with the others

Comment: You would either have to go with the simple one line (at the top of my answer) or restart your main sound when the others are started so they are in sync,  OR write some script that waits until the next loop of your main sound before starting the others

Comment: Thanks! Using the null value works. Interesting, so giving it the null value means it has no value but the object still exist using memory?

Comment: it means e == null, which doesn't take up any additional memory.  Alternatively, you can just make the `e` optional by doing this:  `function toggleSound3(e:MouseEvent = null)`,  now you could just call `toggleSound3()`